# Does anyone have a Rake task to find the routes generated by Sinatra?

Tags: routes, rake, sinatra

Does anyone have a Rake task to find the routes generated by Sinatra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't generate routes like Rails does. You need to define them yourself:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes

Comment: Right. I created some complex REGEX route and am wondering if there is a way to get the list of all the possible routes that the REGEX generated.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `Sinatra::Base.routes`. With those information you can easily generate the rake-task.

Update: There's a [sinatra-rake-routes](https://github.com/wealthsimple/sinatra-rake-routes) gem you could check.